# I can't use Ajv and require/compile in javascript when validating userdata and jsonschema

Tags: javascript

I have json schema and userdata and I need to validate both using javascript. For example here for schema and data. https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/validating-data-with-json-schema-part-1--cms-25343

I tried with the below code,

```
var Ajv = require('ajv');
var ajv = Ajv({allErrors: true});
var valid = ajv.validate(userSchema, userData);
if (valid) {
  console.log('User data is valid');
} else {
  console.log('User data is INVALID!');
  console.log(ajv.errors);
}
```

Here I can't use require and it is saying require not defined.
So I tried one more way that is below one,

```
javascript var validate = ajv.compile(userSchema); 
var valid = validate(userData); 
if (!valid) 
console.log(validate.errors);
```

Here I can't use compile and it is saying compile not defined.

I have 3 types of json schema and one string type user data. Jsonschema has fixed one and user data value will be change as per the requirements. The user data string json have each line as a each record and take one by one and validate with jsonschema. 
Already loaded

```
var userdata = response.split('\n').map(function(line) {
       return line.split('\n');
      });
      for (let i = 0; i < userdata.length; i++) {
      fields = userdata[i];
      var result = fields.toString().split('=');
      tag = result[0];
      value = result[1];
      var payload = value.replace(/\\,/g, ',');

      var type = tag.split('.')[1];

      if (type == 'AA') {
        schema = AA_schema;
      }
      else if (type == 'BB') {
        schema = BB_schema;
      }
      else if (type == 'CC') {
        schema = CC_schema;
      }
      var Ajv = require('ajv'); //Error- Require is not defined
      var ajv = Ajv({allErrors: true});
      var valid = ajv.validate(schema, payload);
      if (valid) {
          console.log('User data is valid');
      } else {
      console.log('User data is INVALID!');
      // console.log(ajv.errors);
      }
}
```

To validate userdata with jsonschema and provide if valid or not. 
Payload have n no.of records and I am taking one by one and validate and print whether it is valid or not, then increase the for loop for 2nd record and do the same till for loop exit.